# Is is faster to filter and get data or filter then get data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have this kind of request :

```
SELECT myTable.ID,
myTable.Adress,
-- 20 more columns of all kind of type
FROM myTable
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM myLink 
    WHERE myLink.FID = myTable.ID 
    and myLink.FID2 = 666)
```

myLink has a lot of rows.

Do you think it's faster to do like this :

```
INSERT INTO @result(ID) SELECT myLink.FID 
FROM myLink 
WHERE myLink.FID2 = 666

UPDATE @result SET Adress = myTable.Adress,
    -- 20 more columns of all kind of type 
    FROM myTable 
    WHERE myTable.ID = @result.ID
```

Comment: Your two queries are very different - the first one only selects, the second does an update. Are you asking about different ways to select or different ways to update?

Comment: Are you just trying to force a link from one table into another for all "matching IDs?"  ie: your myLink is your master table, the myTable is some othe working table, and you want to update all records in one into the other (or tables are vice-versa)?  Or... are there other processes going on against the @result extract.

Comment: The result of the 2 queries are the same : I have a table with an ID and data from myTable and I have only the record that are linked to the ID2 666.
The difference is that on the first I get the data and I select the records in the same time. In the second request I select the record and once I have my record's ID , I get the data.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to select as few rows as possible.  Using a where clause to filter data is a good idea, because then the server has to return less data.  In the second version, you're selecting only one item of myLink, and then working on it, whereas in the first example youve got a select *, which is usually a bad idea.

Is there anything wrong with:

```
SELECT myTable.etc from myTable,myLink where myLink.FID2= 666 AND myLink.ID=myTable.ID
```

This constructs a join and filters in one step.  Perhaps a different kind of join would work more efficiently, but the code sure looks shorter.

Comment: When you use exists you can use "select*" there is no difference 

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/26/sql-server-select-1-vs-select-an-interesting-observation/

And I don't like to do a join only to filter data cause you can get duplicate rows.